# Docker for Mac not forwarding ports

Tags: macos, docker, elasticsearch, kitematic

I'm trying to start elasticsearch 2.4.6 on my Mac (HighSierra).

Using: Docker Kitematic 0.17.2, Docker for Mac 18.06.1

After I download and run selected image in container I have

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
dc5e1f90ce24        elasticsearch:2.4.6   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 hours ago        Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:32782->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32781->9300/tcp   elasticsearch`

But Elastic cannot be reached out on 9200, 9300

`curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

`curl 'http://0.0.0.0:9200/?pretty'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9200: Connection refused`

Isn't 0.0.0.0 should be available?

Comment: the port you should be using is `32782`, i.e. try `curl 'http://localhost:32782/?pretty'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty clear, thanks [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val). But to make it easier I changed in Kitematic mapping ports to 9200, 9300, so now I have

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
a817c85926dc        elasticsearch:2.4.6   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   elasticsearch`

As I expected